# Bootstrap navigationbar overlay text

Tags: html, css

i created with bootstrap an "easy" navigationbar. Now the navigationbar overlay the text. I tried to give the .navbar a margin-bottom of 50px, with no result. Here is the [Page](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Startseite/) and here the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Seite</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="css/meine.css" rel="stylesheet">
      
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Startpage4you</a>
            </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Anmelden</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-4</div>
            <div class="col-md-8">.ccol-md-8</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-4</div>
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

- my stylesheet

```css
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a fixed navbar, you need to add padding to your body just like the bootstrap docs say:

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Answer (score 2):

Because your navigation bar has a fixed property, everything else will appear underneath it, and pushed up to the top of the page.

So you just need to add `margin-top:51px` to your div 'row', in order for it to be seen.

What I would do though, is put the div class row inside a container, and then apply the margin-top to the container. Then you can use that for subsequent pages.

Comment: If you use the container, that would be the best solution. Then the rest of you page content will go inside it, and it will keep the page nice and correctly spaced out between the nav bar, and the rest of the page.